# If you want. It's your call.

Tags: meaning

My friend answered me with this sentence:
If you want. It's your call.

What does "It's your call" mean?

Comment: Try this: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=define+%22it%27s+your+call%22 .

Answer (score 4):

*It's your call* means:

> It's your choice. I'll go along with whatever you decide.

Answer (score 0):

you can accept or refuse his proposal. It's your call.

It's your call" means it's your decision or up to you to decide. According to The Free Dictionary and Cambridge, the noun "call"  also means "decision" in informal English.